# how to configure the email auth infomation in lvs+keepalived's config file

Tags: linux, email, cluster-computing

I setup a lvs+keepalived system for mysql.I keeped the below config in the keepalived.conf :

```
global_defs {
        notification_email {
                sysadm@myweb.com
        }
        notification_email_from sysadm@myweb.com
        smtp_server mail.myweb.com
        smtp_connect_timeout 30
        router_id MYSQL_HA_1
}
```

But i got the error:

```
localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[11751]: SMTP connection ERROR to [0.0.0.0]:25.
```

I think it is because I can not send email without auth infomation in the config file.

My question is how to configure email auth for smtp server with auth infomation in my config file?My smtp server is out of the ha-system.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve a similar issue I was seeing in keepalived.log:

```
SMTP connection ERROR to [0.0.0.0]:25
```

Where my keepalived.conf looked like:

```
global_defs {
  notification_email {
    ....
  }
  notification_email_from somplace@somewhere.com
  smtp_server smtp.somehwere.com
  smtp_connect_timeout 30
  ...
}
```

I updated my smtp configuration to use IP address rather than hostname for my smtp server:

```
smtp_server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Resulting in new output and successful email notifications after restarting keepalived:

```
Remote SMTP server [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25 connected.
```

I assumed this was due to a DNS issue (potentially due to missing dnsmasq service) and could also be resolved by manually defining a host record.